# Node.js, NPM - How can I see docs for old version of package

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npmjs

For example, right now there is "apn" module v2.1.3 on npmjs: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

But there is issue. And I'm using 1.7.8.

I know that I can go to node_modules/apn/ and read README.md.
But I wonder if there is way to see docs for 1.7.8 on npmjs.com?

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn@1.7.8, it doesn't work, but it would be good feature.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option would be to see the docs on GitHub.

A link for this specific example:

- https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/tree/v1.7.8#readme

But it is possible (though unlikely) that some module may not be available on GitHub (or not be tagged properly). In that case you'd need to get the metadata from:

- https://registry.npmjs.org/apn/v1.7.8

Download the tarball:

- http://registry.npmjs.org/apn/-/apn-1.7.8.tgz

and extract it to get the docs.

Comment: Good idea. The issue here that not all authors manage tags on github for their modules

Comment: @DmitriyEroshenko True. In that case you'd have to extract the docs from the tarball yourself - see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this is option too. But as I mentioned above, I can see README.md in node_modules/apn/README.md after module installed, but there is no markdown formatting when I open in editor and there is no way to share link with another developer. So, main issue that npm website doesn't let to see docs for certain version of module. Looks like this is not possible. I wrote question directly to their support, will see if there any way to do it.

Comment: @DmitriyEroshenko Please post a comment here when you get any response from them. It would be great if it was possible to see readme for old versions of modules directly on the npm website.

Comment: This is what I got: 

================================
Thanks for emailing. What you are doing is probably the best solution. 
We aren't able to show all the package versions README.md on the website, 
however you can still download the tarballs for any version of any package in the registry. 
For example, https://registry.npmjs.org/apn/-/apn-1.7.8.tgz is the direct link to the 
tarball for the package you're using, which would include all the docs 
that were included at that publish.

I hope this helps. Let me know if there is anything else I can 
do for you. I'll be here to help.